# Get the labeled data from a custom vision

Tags: object-detection, microsoft-custom-vision

I've trained an object detection model with custom vision, with data that I have labeled with the interface and I was wondering if I could export these labels. I looked around to see if we can but I didn't find any information about this. 
I have exported the model but now I want the labeled data. Does anyone have a clue on how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetTaggedImages` method return all the images with their bounding boxes.

Reference: https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Training_3.0/operations/5c771cdcbf6a2b18a0c3b7fc